# mui typography overide table format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mdxjs

I have a site that imports markdown or mdx files and renders them.
I have formatted the normal markdown tables using

`table: (props) => <Typography variant="table">{props.children}</Typography>`

this works fine.

however, I have a component that wraps a markdown table in mdx.

```
<Wrapper>

| table head 1 | table head 2 |
| ------------ | ------------ |
| table data 1 | table data 2 | 

</Wrapper>
```

I need the table nested within this component to have an entirely different style to a normal table.

when I apply styles to that component, the table is a child and therefore seems to take the default styling.

is there any way of clearing the style of the table for all children?

I've tried using the sx prop on the component to pass in styles for the table. This adds the styles as expected, but I need to clear all the default styles first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css with
1.adding a css class name to the table component
Wrapper className=‘table-wrap’
2. Have something similar to:

```
.table-wrap * {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way of clearing the style of the table for all children?

Yes. Use `<ScopedCssBaseline />` [as described in the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/#scoping-on-children).